# How to adjust heatmap cell height/width?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a simple heatmap with the below code in python. How would I go about adjusting the height/width of the individual heatmap cells with matplotlib?

```
def HeatMap(data):

    # plot the figure

    figure = plt.figure()
    sub_figure = figure.add_subplot(111)
    heatmap = sub_figure.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest',cmap='jet')

    # add a color bar

    cbar = figure.colorbar(ax=sub_figure, mappable=one_box, orientation='horizontal')
    cbar.set_label('Scores')

    plt.show()
```

I have tried `figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))` for example but it increases/decreases the whole figure rather than the individual cells. So far I have this:

[image]

I want the cells to be smaller in height so a bit squished.

Comment: The cell size is a  consequence of the axes size. The size of the axes is (by default) a result of the figure size (plus the size of further elements in the figure). So adjusting the figure size is indeed an option; in which case using the `aspect="auto"` option for `imshow` would make sense. Else you can also set a custom aspect like `aspect=0.5`.

Comment: Thanks, I've set 0.1 and it works like a charm when I increase the size of my dataset alongside the Y axis as well. If you want to post an answer I will mark it as one.